# Control 12 V from 3.3 V

Tags: voltage, raspberry-pi, control

What I'm tring to do is replace a potentiometer on a 12 V LED circuit with my Pi, to control the brightness.

I'm not really sure on what a simple solution to this would be, especially because I'd like to be able to control a bunch of these 12 V LEDs separately from the Pi. I understand you can use PWM, but that causes flickering which would be annoying for photography.

If I have a 0-3.3 V range, how do I go about using that to control a 12 V circuit with a 0-12 V range?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need a "digitally controlled constant current LED driver". Searching for these terms will result in some possibilities.

I found two kinds of solutions:

1. Bare chips like the TLC5947 or TPS6106x. You communicate with them through a digital interface like SPI to set the intensity. Adafruit sells a breakout board for the TLC5947 [here](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1429).
2. 0-10V dimmable LED drivers like these:

http://www.ltechonline.com/html/en/Dimmable-LED-Driver/0-1-10V/0-1-10V_CC_Driver/

You provide a voltage between 0-10V to set the LED intensity. You can generate this voltage with the Rpi using PWM.

There also may be dimmable LED drivers which have a PWM input to control the intensity.

In each case you should read up on how the dimming is performed. Often it is done with PWM. But if the PWM frequency is fast enough it may not matter.